# Training a simple net doesn't appear to change values of variables more than once

Tags: tensorflow

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Here's the tail end of my code:

```
# simple loss function
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.sub(x4, yn)))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.000001).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    print(sess.run([tf.reduce_sum(w1), tf.reduce_sum(b1)]))
    for i in range(5):
        # fill in x1 and yn
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x1: in_images, yn: out_images})
        print(sess.run([tf.reduce_sum(w1), tf.reduce_sum(b1)]))
```

The network descending from the loss function is a simple CNN, with conv2d's and bias_adds, and elu's. I wanted to take a look at how the weights and biases for the first layer change. The first print returns the expected values ([ +/- 100 or so, 0]), as w1 was initialized with a random normal and b1 initialized with zeros.

The second print statement gives a different value pair, as expected.

What's not expected is that each time through the loop, the second print statement prints the same value pair, as though each invocation of train_step is doing the same thing each time, rather than updating the values of the Variables in the loss network.

What am I missing here?

Here's a cut and paste of the interesting part of the run:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:806] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
[-50.281082, 0.0]
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:213] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.98GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
[112.52832, 0.078026593]
[112.52832, 0.078026593]
[112.52832, 0.078026593]
[112.52832, 0.078026593]
[112.52832, 0.078026593]
```

I can post the network itself if necessary, but I suspect the problem is my mental model of how tensorflow updates state.

---

Here's the entire python program, with a dummy routine for the image input to show the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc

H = 128
W = 128

x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, H, W, 1], "input_image")
yn = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, H-12, W-12, 1], "test_image")

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7, 7, 1, 64]))   # 7x7, 1 input chan, 64 output chans
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[64]))
x2 = tf.nn.conv2d(x1, w1, [1,1,1,1], "VALID")
x2 = tf.nn.bias_add(x2, b1)
x2 = tf.nn.elu(x2)

w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 64, 32]))  # 5x5, 64 input 32 output chans
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[32]))
x3 = tf.nn.conv2d(x2, w2, [1,1,1,1], "VALID")
x3 = tf.nn.bias_add(x3, b2)
x3 = tf.nn.elu(x3)

w3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 32, 1]))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1]))
x4 = tf.nn.conv2d(x3, w3, [1,1,1,1], "VALID")
x4 = tf.nn.bias_add(x4, b3)
x4 = tf.nn.elu(x4)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.sub(x4, yn)))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

# fake for testing
in_images = np.random.rand(20, 128, 128, 1)
out_images = np.random.rand(20, 116, 116, 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    print(sess.run([tf.reduce_mean(w1), tf.reduce_mean(b1)]))
    for i in range(5):
        # fill in x1 and yn
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x1: in_images, yn: out_images})
        print(sess.run([tf.reduce_mean(w1), tf.reduce_mean(b1)]))
```

I've looked at a bunch of other training examples and I'm still not seeing what I am doing wrong. Changing the learning rate will just change the numbers printed but the behavior remains the same, no apparent change from running the optimizer.

Comment: Why are you using this super small learning rate of 0.000001? Maybe the training just gets stuck after the first step?

Comment: The results are the same regardless of the learning rate. I've tried rates in the range .01 to .000001.

Comment: (By "same" I mean the behavior is the same -- one change of values only. The numbers will differ based on the learning rate.)

Comment: I'm suspicious of that "Ran out of memory" message. It might not be as harmless as it claims. Can you try making your model smaller (e.g., reduce the batch size) and see if it still happens?

Comment: OK, I changed the CNN sizes to avoid the memory message. No different.

Comment: I inserted the entire program that exhibits the failure mode.

Comment: Huh. If I change the optimizer to MomentumOptimizer instead, the failure mode doesn't happen; the results do change per iteration. WTF.

Answer (score 1):

The error was in the way I computed my loss function. I just added up all of the errors across the batch, rather than taking the mean error for each pair of images. The following loss function

```
# simple loss function
diff_image = tf.abs(tf.sub(x4,yn))
# sum over all dimensions except batch dim
err_sum = tf.reduce_sum(diff_image, [1,2,3])
#take mean over batch
loss = tf.reduce_mean(err_sum)
```

actually starts converging with the AdamOptimizer. The GradientDescentOptimizer still exhibits the "change once only" feature, and I'll go treat it as a bug and post on github.